# What is the difference between ` and $( in Bash?

Tags: bash

What's the difference between

```
failed_instance=`aws deploy`
```

and

```
failed_instance=$(aws deploy)
```

I'm talking about ` and $(?

Answer (score 5):

Both are semantically identical, and both are mandated by the POSIX sh standard, but `$()` is the newer, modern syntax.

- Backslash handling is the same as usual inside `$()`, but backslashes require escaping (*lots* of escaping if nesting) inside backticks.
- It nests cleanly. Compare

  ```
  printf '%s\n' "$(foo "$(bar)")"     # new POSIX sh syntax
  ```

  to its old-style equivalent...

  ```
  printf '%s\n' "`foo \"\`bar\`\"`"   # legacy Bourne syntax
  ```

Comment: Your answer is excellent, as always; however, it would be better if you marked obvious duplicates as such instead of answering them. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Didn't remember the other instance until after answering, and when I got there, Keith had beat me to it.

Comment: I never find any answers that are not on the tag wiki either. I added this one there.